# Computing the complex Riemann integral $\int_0^{i}e^zdz$ in C

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Here is what I have so far,
trying to apply Complex Riemann integration

$$\int_0^{i}e^zdz = \left[e^z\right]_0^{i}=\left[e^x\cos y+ie^x\sin y\right]_0^{i}=\cos i+i\sin i +1$$

However my intuition tells me I have made some error

Comment: WHat does $\int_0^if(z)\,\mathrm dz$ mean?

Comment: we are integrating from $z\in[0,i]

Comment: And what does $[0,i]$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the integral of $z\in[0,i],\Re(z)=0$ then you can make the substitution $x=z/i$ so $dz=idx$:
$$I=i\int_0^1e^{ix}dx=\left[e^{ix}\right]_0^1=e^{i}-1=\cos(1)+i\sin(1)-1$$